# Interpolation by pressure

Tags: interpolation

I have a table with 3 variables: sampling station, pressure (decibar) and temperature. For each of my 46 stations, I have the temperature by pressure. Like so:

```
Station Pressure Temperature
B         0.25        1.2
B         0.33        1.21
B         0.77        1.22
…
```

Now, I simply want to interpolate the data (pressure and temperature) per 1 decibar for each station so I have the following result:

```
Station Pressure Temperature
B       1      1.5
B       2      1.54
B       3      1.59
...
```

Is there an easy way to do this using `interp1`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  In particular you have not listed or tagged an implementation language or library.  Nor have you discussed how your data is stored.